# Select columns in same row as MAX(column)

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

OK, here is my SQL, and I'm using MySQL:

```
SELECT 
  assets.id,  
  IF(max(asset_checkins.time) IS NULL AND max(asset_checkouts.time) IS NOT NULL, 'checked-out', 
    IF(max(asset_checkouts.time) > max(asset_checkins.time), 'checked-out',  
    'checked-in')
  ) 'status',  
  asset_checkouts.user, asset_checkouts.location  
FROM 
  assets  
  left outer join asset_checkouts on asset_checkouts.asset = assets.id  
  left outer join asset_checkins on asset_checkins.asset = assets.id  
group by assets.id;
```

The problem is that the user and location columns are not coming from the row corresponding to the max(psdl_asset_checkouts.time) for that asset.

Instead I get:

```
id  status          user    location  
15  checked-out     1       4<-this  
16  checked-out     1       4
```

When I want to get:

```
id  status          user    location  
15  checked-out     1       7<-this  
16  checked-out     1       4
```

Here is the asset_checkouts table, the value I want is the "7"; the value corresponding to the max(time) **for asset 15**.

```
id      user    asset   time            location  
3       1       15      7/30/12 12:29   4  
14      1       15      7/31/12 11:01   7
```

My thought is that I will need to do a sub-select, but I'm not sure the best way of doing it.

Comment: Can you post your table schema, some example data, and what you expect the result set to be?

Comment: I reformatted the table schema, and result sets, to make them easier to read.

Comment: First, you should avoid selecting bare columns that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause; they should always be handled with an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html). Otherwise MySQL will just give you a random value of that column in the group! Second, your question seems to be a variation of the [get top N rows per group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem. Check out those related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty but it works.  It will return the latest status of the asset and the user and location where it was either checked out or checked in.  This might have worked a little better if the checkins and checkouts were in the same table.

```
SELECT id,`status`,user,location FROM
    (
     SELECT a.id, 'checked-out' `status`,co.`time`, co.user, co.location
     FROM assets a left join asset_checkouts co on a.id=co.asset

     UNION ALL

     SELECT a.id, 'checked-in' `status`, ci.`time`, ci.user, ci.location
     FROM assets a left join asset_checkins ci on a.id=ci.asset
     WHERE NOT ci.`time` IS NULL
    ) U

WHERE `time` = GREATEST((SELECT COALESCE(MAX(`time`),0)
                         FROM asset_checkouts co
                         WHERE co.asset=U.id),
                        (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(`time`),0) 
                         FROM asset_checkins ci
                         WHERE ci.asset=U.id))
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Although I think I am going to consider moving checkins and checkouts to the same table.